# String unable to format with html chars in it

Tags: python, string

I have a code something like below

```
 """<div id="spc-preview-edit-submit" class="spc-form">
    <form action="{% url new-submission itemtype='%s' %}" 
    ...
    ...
    </div></form></div>""" % value
```

I am getting `%u format: a number is required, not unicode` error.

I tried using `format()` with double braces but, its even raising errors..

Can anyone tell a simple and elegant solution

Comment: You've just got some extra `%` characters in there. Escape them and you should be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape the additional `'%'`s:

```
"""<div id="spc-preview-edit-submit" class="spc-form">
    <form action="{%% url new-submission itemtype='%s' %%}" 
    ...
    ...
    </div></form></div>""" % value
```

using `str.format()`, format requires you to escape additional `{` using `{{`:

```
 """<div id="spc-preview-edit-submit" class="spc-form">
    <form action="{{% url new-submission itemtype='{}' %}}" 
    ...
    ...
    </div></form></div>""".format(value)
```